# Google Drive setWritersCanShare(false) and update of a File in JAVA

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to put the option "setWritersCanShare" of a file to FALSE. Now I am the owner of the file and I want that the file editors can't share the File. I can get the file and change its permission (via API) without problmes,  but when I try to change the "setWritersCanShare" option, I get this response:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file 0B0o1ZH_FIoLGUER2UFptYi1CVEU",
    "reason" : "userAccess"
  } ],
  "message" : "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file 0B0o1ZH_FIoLGUER2UFptYi1CVEU"
}
```

This is the file update code:

```
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName("La fiesta").build();

File file = service.files().get(fileID).execute();
file.setWritersCanShare(false);
File fileUpdate=service.files().update(fileID, file).execute();
```

What it's my error?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the operation in the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and see if the result is the same.

The error seems to indicate that the authenticated user isn't actually the owner of the file. Are you sure you're authenticating as the file owner (not a Service Account)?